# initialize struct with substructs

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to create a struct with values of other structs. For example a `Filter`:

```
type ForSaleFilter struct {
        Search string
}
type JobFilter struct {
        JobType string
}
type Filter struct {
        ForSale ForSaleFilter
        Jobs JobFilter

}
```

I can't seem to figure out a better way to create the struct than this long line of code:

`filter := Filter{ForSale: ForSaleFilter{Search: "cool stuff"}}`

Is there a better way I can create this? Something like

`filter := Filter{ForSale{Search: "cool stuff"}}`

would be ideal. Maybe I could restructure my structs to do this?

Comment: Honestly, how big of a problem is it to add just the struct name in the construction code? *You would not want to restructure your classes based on how much you have to type, rather on what's right for the application.*

Comment: Well, I am creating a package and I would like it to be as streamlined as possible.

Comment: @crazyGamer emitting the word `ForSale` and changing `ForSaleFilter` to `ForSale` seems to work.

Comment: There is a difference between the two approaches, beyond cosmetics - what you have done now is **composition**, which is one of the object-oriented patterns of Go for supporting inheritance in a way. If that better serves the purpose of your module, it is a good approach.

Comment: maybe you could explain what the difference is for the answer?

Comment: In your case, type embedding seems to cause no harm. For a better understanding, I would recommend reading [this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) section. Main uses: implicitly implement interfaces, reduce book-keeping, convenience, alternative to inheritence.

Comment: You know you can put each field on it's own line right? It makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @crazyGamer Embedding structs is **not the same** as inheritance. Go doesn't have inheritance because it isn't object oriented.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: I completely agree, I **never said they are  the same**, I just said the closest to that in Go is embedding - see this line from [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding): "Go does not provide the typical, type-driven notion of subclassing, but it does have the ability to “borrow” pieces of an implementation by embedding types within a struct or interface."

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable for basic types, or for a struct that contains only basic types, the variable is also initialized in Go.

Thus, after declaration, it can be used immediately.

```
var filter Filter
filter.ForSale.Search = "cool stuff"
```

or

```
filter := Filter{}
filter.ForSale.Search = "cool stuff"
```